# MySQL Errors - phpBB3

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb3

Being a complete noob at PHP, I've been trying to install phpBB3 with several mods. However, something has broken the site and I can't receive support from the official forums unless I know which mod is causing the problems. Here is the error message I'm receiving:

```
    SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*, pb.id AS pb_id, pb.holding AS pb_holding FROM (phpbb_users u CROSS JOIN phpbb' at line 1 [1064]

SQL

SELECT u.*, z.friend, z.foe, p.*, gu.personal_album_id, gu.user_images, .*, pb.id AS pb_id, pb.holding AS pb_holding FROM (phpbb_users u CROSS JOIN phpbb_posts p) LEFT JOIN phpbb_zebra z ON (z.user_id = 2 AND z.zebra_id = p.poster_id) LEFT JOIN phpbb_gallery_users gu ON (gu.user_id = p.poster_id) LEFT JOIN phpbb_points_bank pb ON (pb.user_id = p.poster_id) WHERE p.post_id = 3 AND u.user_id = p.poster_id

BACKTRACE

FILE: (not given by php)
LINE: (not given by php)
CALL: msg_handler()

FILE: [ROOT]/includes/db/dbal.php
LINE: 757
CALL: trigger_error()

FILE: [ROOT]/includes/db/mysqli.php
LINE: 189
CALL: dbal->sql_error()

FILE: [ROOT]/viewtopic.php
LINE: 1050
CALL: dbal_mysqli->sql_query()
```

I'm not sure what other info I should post here, but feel free to ask. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a points mod? Maybe it is the one causing the problem

Comment: I do, but it was working fine on it's own. I was a bit silly and didn't back up my database between each mod install. :(

Comment: Check this link, https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2129904 it says you need to make sure you did all the edits

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the file containing this in the ultimate points mod, and add a `,`after it, to be like this

```
'SELECT'        => 'u.*, z.friend, z.foe, p.*, pb.id AS pb_id, pb.holding AS pb_holding,
```

Source is this [link](http://www.bbcode.pl/baza-modyfikacji-f29/ultimate-points-t1277-90.html#p15230), but it is in Polish.

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, that line is already edited correctly. The points mod was working, it appears to be a problem with another mod

Comment: In your query the problem is in the ``, .*,`` which probably should be ``, pb.*,``, ``, gu.*,`` or left out completely. Without your code it's hard to debug. Could you provide the current SELECT definition (as above) from the points mod and the gallery mod?